# Not getting data back from PayPal

Tags: asp-classic, paypal

I am working on a new site that is posting payment information to PayPal. I am successful getting all of my information posted to PayPal. My problem is that when I choose to return to my site after the user completes the payment, no form data is passed back. It appears to be using GET to submit the form to my page.

This was working for me before in everything but FireFox. I am already aware of the problem there and I am working to fix that, but this is now happening in Chrome.

I just changed the cmd variable to _cart from _xclick so that I could pass the entire cart instead of just the calculated total.

This is what I am using to post to PayPal (altered to protect the innocent):

```
    <form action="<%= PAYPAL_IPN_ADDRESS %>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="<%= PAYPAL_VARIABLE_EVENTID %>" value="<%= myId %>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<%= MY_URL %>/returnpage.asp" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<%= MY_URL %>/cancelpage.asp" />
            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<%= MY_URL %>/myipnlistener.asp" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<%= Settings(SETTING_PAYMENT_PAYPALADDRESS) %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to <%= SiteInfo.Name %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<%= GetCurrencyValue() %>" />
<%
        for i = 0 to details.Count - 1
            response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""item_name_" & i + 1 & """ value=""" & details(i).ItemDescription & """/>"
            response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""item_number_" & i + 1 & """ value=""" & details(i).LineNumber & """/>"
            response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""amount_" & i + 1 & """ value=""" & FormatNumber(details(i).Price, 2) & """/>"
            response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""quantity_" & i + 1 & """ value=""" & details(i).Quantity & """/>"
        next
%>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your variable says IPN. Do you mean PDT? IPN is not for end users.

Comment: Yes, and the IPN part is working correctly. It is the "return" page that is the problem. It is not receiving the form post which has my custom field that I am looking for.

Comment: Do you have PDT and Auto-Return enabled in the PayPal profile?

Comment: Looks like you may be missing the rm parameter, too.  rm = 2 to get a POST.

Comment: Ok Andrew, your comment about rm = 2 worked. If you will write that as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

after going through your code i see that you are using

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<%= MY_URL %>/returnpage.asp" />
```

you have to change this to

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<%= MY_URL %>/returnpage.asp" />
```

After this your all errors will be gone.